# Extract all unique variables from a formula

Tags: r

I have the formula for an `lm()` model stored as a `chr` variable, and I'm try to extract all of the variables from the formula into a vector.

To make it replicable, with the `mtcars` variables: `mpg`, `cyl`, and `drat` (and my formula has transformations etc as in the example)

```
model_string <- "mpg ~ cyl + I(abs(0.5-drat)) + I((0.5 - drat)^2)"
```

My desired output is:

```
vars_used <- c("mpg", "cyl", "drat")
```

So far, what I've done is:

```
library(tidyverse)
vars_used <- model_string %>% 
  str_extract_all(pattern = "\\w+") %>% 
  pluck(1) %>% 
  str_remove_all(pattern = "[0-9]")

vars_used
```

```
[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "I"    "abs"  ""     ""     "drat" "I"    ""     ""     "drat" ""
```

Is there any easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, particularly using tidytext?

I still need to remove the empty strings in the vector, and also remove duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The base package has a function for this:

```
all.vars(as.formula(model_string))
#[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "drat"
```

You should not use text processing in this case.